# IE9 issue, CSS is not loading

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have a problem with CSS on IE9, CSS is not loaded properly, what I am trying?

1. Adding the charset at the top of main.css
2. Change compatibility mode to IE8,9,edge
3. Remove all unnecessary white spaces before doctype.

CSS is not loaded...

My website: http://www.prestahome.com/themes/control/

What can I do with this?

Answer (score 2):

I found this in your html:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 " lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<html lang="en">
```

I think that should be:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 " lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Your current code would show a dubble html tag in IE.

Comment: You have right, thank you for that but CSS is still not loaded. My ideas are finished at this moment...

Answer (score 0):

oh! what a shame!

I completely forgot about the limit of CSS files loaded at one time!

More informations here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ad1b6e88-bbfa-4cc4-9e95-3889b82a7c1d/internet-explorer-imposes-a-maximum-limit-of-32-individual-stylesheet?forum=iewebdevelopment

Comment: and you were loading 42 of them